# C# lambda in StructureMap

Tags: c#, lambda, structuremap4

using StructureMap 4, and me new to C#, i wonder why i get a compilation error:

```
var di = new Container(_ =>
{
    // (1) compile error: CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'StructureMap.IContext' to '...ITest'
    _.For<Func<ITest, ITestRunner>>().Use( arg => new TestRunner(arg) );

    // (2) compiles OK
    Func<ITest, ITestRunner> f1 = arg => new TestRunner(arg);
    _.For<Func<ITest, ITestRunner>>().Use( f1 );

    // (3) with cast compiles ok
    _.For<Func<ITest, ITestRunner>>().Use( (Func<ITest, ITestRunner>)( arg => new TestRunner(arg)));
});
```

Is there a compact syntax, were i don't need the `f1` variable (2) and without the cast repeating the types (3) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the type parameter in the method `For` denotes the type or class for which you want to define a different instance creating delegate. In your code it is `Func<ITest, ITestRunner>`, which tells the `StructureMap` that when I want an object of type `Func<ITest, ITestRunner>`, use whatever I specify in `Use`.

My guess is that you want the map to use a `TestRunner` whenever an `ITest` is added to it. In this case, the type parameter would just be `ITest`, like so:

```
_.For<ITest>().Use(arg => new TestRunner(arg));
```

Note that even if the other two blocks of code *did* compile, they wouldn't give you the required result. Instead, for every `Func<ITest, ITestRunner>`, the `StructureMap` would use the value passed to `Use`.

Comment: Hm, right. What I wanted is to get a "AssistedInject like in Guice". Creating a factory delegate here. But I see the problem is, other fields or ctor args cannot be handled this way.